# load method of jquery unable to load concated url

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-load

Well this is code that is working perfectly like I want to

```
 $("#previous").click(function() {
    var month=$("#previous").attr("name");
    var loadurl="include/calendar.php?month=january";
    $("#calendar").load(loadurl);
    return false;
});
```

Above code simply loads the content from calendar.php exactly I wanted to but when I modified my code to what I actually need the calendar div simply hides display nothing

```
 $("#previous").click(function() {
    var month=$("#previous").attr("name");
    var loadurl="include/calendar.php?month="+month;
    $("#calendar").load(loadurl);
    return false;
});
```

This is the html, $prev_month and $next_month are obtained after some calculations which are January and March respectively for current month(February)

```
 <a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="previous" id="previous" name="<?php echo $prev_month ?> "> </a>
<span class="month">  <?php echo "{$month} {$year}"; ?>  </span>
<a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="next" name="<?php echo $next_month ?>" id="next"> </a>
```

I can't seem to find the problem.
Can you identify the fault here and also Please tell me where  I can see jquery error so that I can debug any future problem

Comment: you can use console.log("debug_message_here") to debug your scripts. You can use the google-chrome developer tools to use the advanced debugging features like breakpoints, watchs', etc.

Comment: Please show your HTML to check if you are really setting the name attribute on the #previous element and if it is what's expected.

Comment: Also, as @sandeepraju adviced, you can use Firebug on Firefox or the Developer Tools on google Chrome to inspect your html and/or debug your javascript.

Comment: @RobertoLinares I have edited my question and added html. Once again I am pointing out that top code seems to work fine without any problem